# Calculate items, loop by month, adding month each time through

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have a table of tickets. I am trying to calculate how many tickets were "open" at each month end over the course of the current year. As well, I am pushing this to a bar chart and I am needing out put this into an array through LINQ.

My SQL query to get my calculation is:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblMaintenanceTicket t WHERE (CreateDate < DATEADD(MM, 1, '01/01/2012')))
    -
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblMaintenanceTicket t WHERE (CloseDate < DATEADD(MM, 1, '01/01/2012'))) AS 'Open @Month End'
```

My logic is the following: Count all tickets open between first and end of the month. Subtract that count from the tickets closed before the end of the month.

**UPDATED:**
I have updated my query with the comments below and it is not working with errors in the GROUP, but I am not truly understanding the logic I guess, my lack of skill in SQL is to blame.

I have added a SQL Fiddle example to show you my query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9b638/1

Desired output:

```
-----------
| Jan | 3 |
-----------
| Feb | 4 |
-----------
| Mar | 0 |
-----------
```

Comment: Need a bit more information. You have it tagged as VB.NET, but no VB code. What problem exactly are you running into?

Comment: I am looking to convert this into VB LINQ. I am not exaclty sure how I can calculate all the months and counts (looping?) within a LINQ query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL has several erros . . . are grouping by `CreateDate` but you don't have it as a column from the subqueries.  And, you don't have a column alias on the `count(*)`.

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
select DATENAME(MONTH,CreateDate), DATEPART(YEAR,CreateDate),
       (sum(case when CreateDate < DATEADD(MM, 1, '01/01/2012') then 1 else 0 end) -
        sum(case when CloseDate < DATEADD(MM, 1, '01/01/2012') then 1 else 0 end)
       )
from tblMaintenanceTicket
group by DATENAME(MONTH,CreateDate), DATEPART(YEAR,CreateDate)
```

Your comment seems to elucidate what you want clearer than your question (the explanation in the question is a bit buried).  What you need is a driver table of months and then join this to your table.  Something like:

```
select mons.yr, mons.mon, count(*) as OpenTickets
from (select month(CreateDate) as mon, year(CreateDate) as yr,
             cast(min(CreateDate) as date) as MonthStart,
             cast(max(CreateDate) as date) as monthEnd
      from tblMaintenanceTicket
      group by month(CreateDate), year(CreateDate) 
     ) mons left outer join
     tblMaintenanceTicket mt
     on mt.CreateDate <= mons.MonthEnd and
        (mt.CloseDate > mons.MonthEnd or mt.CloseDate is null)
group by mons.yr, mons.mon
```

I am assuming records are created on every day.  This is a convenience so I don't have to think about getting the first and last day of each month using other SQL functions.

Comment: Sorry this query doesnt take into account the constraints I need. I need to know "at the end of each month" how many tickets were open.

My logic is the following: Count all tickets open between first and end of the month. Subtract that count from the tickets closed before the end of the month.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9b638/1

Comment: Sorry I tried to clarify more in my original post. Hopefully it makes more sense. Sorry its so confusing.

I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: @Chuck . . . Don't apologize.  It is probably harder to write a clear question than a clear answer.  I should have read the question better.

Comment: There is though the potential a record is not created everyday, which is why I was getting the first and last day (or trying to) in my original query.

Error qwith the query, but I think its the group by http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9b638/5

Comment: Your example works quite well, although the counts seem to be off. I would expect the result to be different in the open tickets as of the end of each month.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9b638/6

Comment: The problem was the `group by` (which you added to fix the issue with the `min` and `max`).  I fixed the group by and tested it on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Yep that is correct now actually, the counts are exactly as they should be. THANK YOU! Now to convert this to LINQ for my app ;-p

Answer (score 1):

If your query is returning what you need, then simply use `DATENAME(MONTH, yourDate)` to retrieve the month and group by Month,Year:

```
 SELECT SUM(*), DATENAME(MONTH,yourDate), DATEPART(YEAR,yourDate)
 FROM
 (
     your actual query here
 )
 GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,yourDate), DATEPART(YEAR,yourDate)
```

Comment: I just figured out there was a CreateDate AND a CloseDate, I'll adjust the query in some minutes, but you get the point

Comment: On second thought, your question does not take into consideration `CloseDate` as you specified "calculate how many tickets were opened at each month"

Comment: Oops... I am trying to calculate how many tickets were "open" at the month end. Sorry, not opened, but open "still".

Comment: @Chuck: Please consider editing your question to clarify the confusing bit.

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully it is better. My SQL statement returns the count I need at the moment, but I need to loop through each month and return a set of data for the year

Comment: THen simply SELECT SUM(*),DATENAME(MONTH,yourDate) and GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,yourDate).

Comment: I have added a SQL Fiddle example to work with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9b638/1